# mysql regexp for matching fields containing non-anchor tags with href attribute containing a pattern

Tags: mysql, regex

I am trying to find all the rows from database whose field have non-anchor tags whose href attribute start with {clickurl} string. For example this -

```
<link foo="bar" href="{clickurl}http://wwww.google.com" ...
```

Or this (since it has one non-anchor tag matching the criteria) -
    http://wwww.google.com" ...
    http://wwww.google.com" ...

But not this (since it is an anchor tag) - 
    http://wwww.google.com" ...

**What I have done so far**

With the following regexp, I am able to get all records where link tag has href attribute starting with  {clickurl} -

```
SELECT bannerid FROM ox_banners WHERE htmltemplate REGEXP "<link[^>]*href\s*=\s*[\"'][^>]*{clickurl}(.*)[\"']"
```

But, since I need to search for not only link tags but any other tag (excluding anchor tag), I modified the regexp to -

```
SELECT bannerid FROM ox_banners WHERE htmltemplate REGEXP "<[!a][^>]*href\s*=\s*[\"'][^>]*{clickurl}(.*)[\"']"
```

But this is also returning rows where anchor tags contain this pattern.

**Updates**

With inputs from zx81, I am now using this expression`<[^a][^>]*href[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*[\"'][^>]*{clickurl}(.*)[\"']` and only non anchor tags are matching in normal case, but in cases like the following, when href attribute is on a tag which is inside an echo statement within a PHP tag, it is also getting matched (not desired) since actually it is an href on an anchor tag -

```
<?php

$GLOBALS['test'] = '{clickurl}tel://test';

echo '<a href="{clickurl}test">Test</a>';

?>
```

The

I am still looking for this fix.

Comment: Person who downvoted, please add some reason..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex instead:

```
< *[^a][^>]+ *href *= *"{clickurl}
```

You were almost there. It looks like you had a small typo: you had `[!a]` instead of `[^a]` to mean "one character that is not an "a".

The `[^a]` and `[^>]` are almost the same. I am sure you know this, but in both cases, the `^` means "not", so `[^>]` is any character that is not a `>`

Instead of  `*` if you want to allow not only for space characters but other kinds of whitespace, you can use `[[:space:]]*`

Thanks to Tuga for reminding me that `\s` doesn't work in MySQL: it matches a literal "s". I had "spaced out" on this one. :)

Comment: MySQL does not support any shorthand character classes

Comment: also `< *` isn't valid because quantifiers(`*`) can only be used after a token that can be repeated, this is valid: `< .*`

Comment: @tuga in ` *` the star applies to the space character, which can be repeated.

Comment: @tuga It's getting late, bro. :) I'm getting cross-eyed, hanging up, see you next time.

Comment: @SandeepanNath Hello again Sandeepan. Hey did this solve your problem, or are you still wrestling with it? Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @zx81 Thanks for pointing out that I was using instead of . So far, I am able to get match results with this regex - `<[^a][^>]*href\s*=\s*[\"'][^>]*{clickurl}(.*)[\"']`, but this also returning those records which have href attribute on a tag which is inside an echo statement within a PHP tag. In that case, the PHP tag unnecessarily matches my pattern. Please see question update.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT bannerid FROM ox_banners WHERE htmltemplate REGEXP ".*<[^a][^>]*href=\"\\{clickurl\\}.*";


Options: Case insensitive; Regex syntax only
Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed) «.*»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as few or as many times as needed to find the longest match in combination with the other quantifiers or alternatives «*»
Match the character “<” literally «<»
Match any single character that is NOT present in the list below and that is NOT a line break character (line feed) «[^a]»
   The literal character “a” (case insensitive) «a»
Match any single character that is NOT present in the list below and that is NOT a line break character (line feed) «[^>]*»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as few or as many times as needed to find the longest match in combination with the other quantifiers or alternatives «*»
   The literal character “>” «>»
Match the character string “href="” literally (case insensitive) «href="»
Match the character “{” literally «\{»
Match the character string “clickurl” literally (case insensitive) «clickurl»
Match the character “}” literally «\}»
Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed) «.*»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as few or as many times as needed to find the longest match in combination with the other quantifiers or alternatives «*»
```